# Mail Internet header analyzer in Python?

Tags: python, parsing, smtp, rfc822

been going through old posts but so far only found solutions for identifying e.g. sender, recipient, subject. I'm looking to get started on code that would analyze the internet header similar to tools like https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/MHA/Pages/mha.aspx and https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/messageheader/ .

I would like to be able to extract e.g. From, Reply-to, submitting MX, X-originating IP, X-mailer. Should I create a parser from scratch or is there something I could use? Perhaps a sample or something you can share?

Best,
Fredrik

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: Noted Prune. Thanks for putting me straight! Will make sure to take this more into consideration for future posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

email module deals with e-mails quite nicely.
For example:

```
import email

msg = email.message_from_file("some_saved_email.eml")
# To get to headers, you treat the Message() as a dict:
print msg.keys() # To get all headers
print msg["X-Mailer"] # To get to header's value

# Let us list the whole header:
for header, value in msg.items():
    print header+": "+value
```

Comment: Great! Thx! Is there a way to get the originating (first) MX as well? What is the best resource to read up on the module with references to values available (as you did with "X-mailer"?

Comment: Did you mean "X-Originating-IP"? To learn how to use the module the best source is Python's documentation. As for values, well they aren't fixed. There are few mandatory headers, others can be omitted. Or substituted with some others. Each mailer adds some specific headers and anti-viruses can join the ball. Not to mention SMTP and POP servers. You really have to see which headers are available in examined mail, then take most likely needed ones out. Google around for e-mail headers and make your own list of those which you will try to get (pay attention to synonymic ones).

Comment: Thanks Dalen! I do have sample headers and now with your guidance read them into a variable, however can't seem to be able to use your syntax? Testing this, which works - headers = Parser().parse(open("mailheader.txt", 'r')) . However, won't accept the print msg["X-Mailer"] for example, but print (headers['From:']) will at least return None . I guess I have stuff to read up on, but if you have a few pointers it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you are using Python 3.x then some changes are introduced in email module so some things from my example might not work. For one thing, if 3.x, try print(msg["X-Mailer"]) - with parenthesis. To get to the steps through which the e-mail passed to get to you, you have to extract all "Received" headers. For full MX records you would have to query them from DNS servers. I.e. get full list of possible servers for each IP or domain listed in "Received" headers.

Comment: When a header is not present, then None is returned. If there is no "From", header well, some other header can substitute it. E.g. "Reply-To" or "Return-Path" or "X-Rcpt-Trace" or "Envelope-From". Although that would be first e-mail I heard of with no standard "From" header. I expect servers wouldn't want even to pass through such an e-mail. Open your e-mail in a text editor and you will be able to compare what is there with what are you getting. I repeat: msg.keys() will return you all existing headers for examined e-mail.

Comment: There were of course some issue with he input file I used for testing - very sorry! Like you said, would have been the first email without From:. I just jumped to conclusion that my code was wrong. Anyway, I have a good starting point now. Seem to get consistent results with e.g. print('Subject: %s' % headers['Subject']) for the Subject. No luck with the print headers.keys() yet though. Thanks again! Really appreciate your help!